# My query is not using my indexes, how do i use explain plan and fix this slow query with MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-execution-plan

I have this query that is running slow (16 seconds), it only has 44085 records in the biggest table. Any suggestions or anything that sticks out?

thanks for any help

```
SELECT  u.`vid`,  u.`userID`,  u.`localConID`,  u.`lastran`,  u.`laststatus`,  
        u.`lastmessage`,  u.`active`
        ,u.`autorundaily`,  u.`autorunmonthly`,  u.`fileslocation`
         ,c.`conid`, c.`fname`, c.`lname`, c.`homephone`, c.`cellphone` , c.`email` , 
        DATE_FORMAT(u.`lastran`,'%d/%m/%y %k:%i') lastranFormatted, u.`retrys`
FROM virtual_alerts_users u
LEFT JOIN virtual_alerts_cons c ON c.referid = u.localConID
WHERE u.userID = 9581
```

When i do an explain i get::

```
  id  |  select_type  |  table  |  type  |  possible_keys  |  key  |  key_len  |  ref  |  rows  |  extra
  1   |  SIMPLE       |  u      |  ALL   |  Index 3        | null  |  null     |  null |  459   |  Using where
  1   |  SIMPLE       |  c      |  ALL   |  null           | null  |  null     | null  |  44085 |
```

The tables look like::

```
CREATE TABLE `virtual_alerts_users` (
`vid` INT(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`userID` INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`localConID` VARCHAR(10) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
`encrpytPW` VARCHAR(100) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
`lastran` TIMESTAMP NULL DEFAULT NULL,
`laststatus` INT(11) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
`lastmessage` TEXT NULL,
`active` TINYINT(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`autorundaily` TINYINT(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`autorunmonthly` TINYINT(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`fileslocation` VARCHAR(512) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
`retrys` TINYINT(4) NULL DEFAULT '0',
PRIMARY KEY (`vid`),
UNIQUE INDEX `Index 2` (`localConID`),
INDEX `Index 3` (`userID`)
)
```

-

```
CREATE TABLE `virtual_alerts_cons` (
`conid` INT(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`userID` INT(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`vid` INT(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`fname` VARCHAR(50) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
`lname` VARCHAR(50) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
`referid` VARCHAR(10) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
`level` VARCHAR(2) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
`status` VARCHAR(2) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
`lang` VARCHAR(15) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
`homephone` VARCHAR(15) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
`cellphone` VARCHAR(15) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
`address` VARCHAR(255) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
`email` VARCHAR(255) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
`birthday_mon` TINYINT(4) NULL DEFAULT '0',
`birthday_day` TINYINT(4) NULL DEFAULT '0',
`anv_mon` TINYINT(4) NULL DEFAULT '0',
`anv_day` TINYINT(4) NULL DEFAULT '0',
`anv_cnt` TINYINT(4) NULL DEFAULT '0',
`lasthash` BIGINT(20) NULL DEFAULT '0',
`lastupdated` TIMESTAMP NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
PRIMARY KEY (`conid`),
UNIQUE INDEX `Index 3` (`userID`, `referid`),
INDEX `Index 2` (`userID`),
INDEX `Index 4` (`vid`)
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have no index on `referid` in `virtual_alerts_cons`, but you do have a combined index on `userID` and `referid`.

To force MySQL to use that, change your join condition to:

```
LEFT JOIN
    virtual_alerts_cons c
ON
    c.referid = u.localConID
        AND
    c.userId = u.userID
```

Alternatively, you could create an additional index on `referid`.

Answer (score -1):

The table virtual_alerts_con doesn't have the right kind of index for referid.

```
CREATE TABLE `virtual_alerts_cons` (
`conid` INT(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`userID` INT(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`vid` INT(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`fname` VARCHAR(50) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
`lname` VARCHAR(50) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
`referid` VARCHAR(10) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
`level` VARCHAR(2) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
`status` VARCHAR(2) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
`lang` VARCHAR(15) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
`homephone` VARCHAR(15) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
`cellphone` VARCHAR(15) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
`address` VARCHAR(255) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
`email` VARCHAR(255) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
`birthday_mon` TINYINT(4) NULL DEFAULT '0',
`birthday_day` TINYINT(4) NULL DEFAULT '0',
`anv_mon` TINYINT(4) NULL DEFAULT '0',
`anv_day` TINYINT(4) NULL DEFAULT '0',
`anv_cnt` TINYINT(4) NULL DEFAULT '0',
`lasthash` BIGINT(20) NULL DEFAULT '0',
`lastupdated` TIMESTAMP NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
PRIMARY KEY (`conid`),
UNIQUE INDEX `Index 3` (`userID`, `referid`),
INDEX `Index 2` (`userID`),
INDEX `Index 5` (`referid`),
INDEX `Index 4` (`vid`)
)
```

You can also probably change the query to something like this

```
SELECT  u.`vid`,  u.`userID`,  u.`localConID`,  u.`lastran`,  u.`laststatus`,  
        u.`lastmessage`,  u.`active`
        ,u.`autorundaily`,  u.`autorunmonthly`,  u.`fileslocation`
         ,c.`conid`, c.`fname`, c.`lname`, c.`homephone`, c.`cellphone` , c.`email` , 
        DATE_FORMAT(u.`lastran`,'%d/%m/%y %k:%i') lastranFormatted, u.`retrys`
FROM virtual_alerts_users u
LEFT JOIN virtual_alerts_cons c ON c.referid = u.localConID AND c.userId = 9581
WHERE u.userID = 9581
```

That will probably take advantage of the Index 3 with both userId and referid.

The explain plan shows you that it is scanning all the rows of the virtual_alerts_con table because it can't use any indexes. Your "Index 3" isn't helping because its a multi-column index. There are restrictions on how you use multi-column indexes.

If you have an index with A, B, C, you can't search on just column C. You can search with just A, or A+B, or A+B+C.